# Unable to render RenderedOp for this operation

Tags: java, jai

I am trying to get rendering for an image which comes from an InputStream and is created by Java Advanced Imaging.

This is the snippet:

```
FileCacheSeekableStream fSeek = new FileCacheSeekableStream(is);
sourceImage = JAI.create("stream", fSeek);

((OpImage) sourceImage.getRendering()).setTileCache(null);
```

The error is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: - Unable to render RenderedOp for this operation.
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createRendering(RenderedOp.java:867)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getRendering(RenderedOp.java:888)
    at com.util.ImageScaleUtil.setSource(ImageScaleUtil.java:139)
```

Tried everything... tried `getNewRendering` instead of `getRendering`, did not work.

Any help?